# Using liquibase with Altibase

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

We already have an existing project with liquibase scripts (mysql, postgresql). Now we want to support a new database named Altibase. But when we run `liquibase:dropAll` `liquibase:update` we got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:dropAll 
(default-cli) on project project-model: Error setting up or running Liquibase: 
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
Data type module (Name="DATETIME") not found. 
[Failed SQL: 
CREATE TABLE ALTIBASE.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (
  ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, 
  LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), 
  CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))] -> [Help 1]
```

Here's the pom's configuration:

```
<profile>
    <id>altibase</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>env</name>
            <value>altibase</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <db.driver>Altibase.jdbc.driver.AltibaseDriver</db.driver>
        <db.url>jdbc:Altibase://ourdomain.cloud:20001/ourdb</db.url>
        <db.schema>ALTIBASE</db.schema>
        <db.username>admin</db.username>
        <db.password>admin</db.password>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.altibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>Altibase</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Note that we installed Altibase jar locally via maven.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the DB is not directly supported by liquibase. And it does not seem to have a data type `DATETIME`.

Checkout the section "Using Unsupported Databases" on the this site: https://www.liquibase.org/databases.html.

Maybe use the optional parameter `--currentDateTimeFunction=<value>`. Also see this site: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

Answer (score 0):

Altibase has `DATE` data type. And, It's `DATE` data type is same with other DBMSs' `DATETIME` data type.
Altibase's `DATE` data type can handle date data with micro seconds unit.